# Interpreting infinite languages in graphs (for Vaught's conjecture)

Tags: logic, model-theory

Vaught's conjecture for first order theories (VC) in its original form states that every complete first order theory of a countable language has either at most countably many isomorphism classes of countable models or else continuum many.

Let $L:=\langle E \rangle$ be a first order language with the binary relation symbol $E$. In the book "The Descriptive Set Theory of Polish Group Actions" by H. Becker and A. Kechris theorem 6.1.3 claims that VC holds if and only if VC holds for $L$-theories of graphs.

The main idea behind this result is that every countable model of a countable language can be interpreted in a graph (seen as a $L$ structure) as demonstrated for example in section 5.5 of Wilfrid Hodges' book "Model Theory".

> Let $S$ be an arbitrary countable relational language and $T_1$ a
>   satisfiable $S$-theory. There is a $L$-formula $\phi_D(v_1)$ and a
>   $L$-theory $T_2$ such that for every $L$-model $\mathcal{M}$ of $T_2$
>   we have $\mathcal{M}\models\exists v_1\phi_D(v_1)$. Furthermore, for
>   each $k<\omega$ and each $k$-ary relation symbol $R$ of $S$ there is a
>   $L$-formula $\psi_R(v_1,\dots ,v_k)$ such that for every model
>   $\mathcal{M}$ of $T_2$ we can define a $S$ model $I(\mathcal{M})$ of
>   $T_1$ in the following way:
>
> 1.) The universe of $I(\mathcal{M})$ is $\{a\in M\mid \mathcal{M}\models\phi_D(a)\}$.
>
> 2.) A $k$-ary relation symbol $R$ of $S$ is interpreted as   $$  \{(a_1,\dots ,a_k)\in I(\mathcal{M})^k\mid \mathcal{M}\models\psi_R(a_1,\dots, a_k)\} $$ If
>   $\mathcal{A}$ is a $S$-model of $T_1$ then we can define a model
>   $\mathcal{M}$ of $T_2$ such that $I(\mathcal{M})\cong\mathcal{A}$.
>   In case $S$ is finite, VC for $S$-theories reduces to VC for
>   $L$-theories because we can easily choose $T_2$ such that for all
>   models $\mathcal{M}, \mathcal{M'}$ of $T_2$, we have
>   $$\mathcal{M}\cong\mathcal{M'}\Leftrightarrow I(\mathcal{M})\cong I(\mathcal{M'}).$$

My problem is that I cannot define $T_2$ in such a way if the language $S$ is infinite. It can happen that $T_1$ has only countably many isomorphism classes while $T_2$ has continuum many. So my question is how can VC for $S$-theories be reduced to VC for $L$-theories if $S$ is infinite?

A possible approach I have been thinking about is to interpret $T_1$ in some other finite language $L_2$ thereby getting a theory $T_3$ which has the same number of isomorphism classes as $T_1$. Can someone help me with that? Thanks!

Comment: I made some formatting edits to your question for readability, including giving the question a more informative title. I hope the edits are ok with you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, the main idea to solve this problem, for those who are interested -apparently not too many- can be found here:

http://home.mathematik.uni-freiburg.de/ziegler/preprints/INTERPR.pdf